# Get physical file path with opening app from Share menu of file browser...?

Tags: android, xml

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is my intent filter...

I want to get the complete file path when I open a file through a file browser via a share menu... The file path should be displayed in a Textview when the app is opened via a share menu of the file... Plz help me I am new to android programming...